# The data is not displayed in the select box

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, devexpress

**Description of the situation**

Connecting to the database [completed]

Downloading relevant data [completed]

I try to display them in the selectbox [zero errors in the console, view as in the attached picture = empty]

**I tried:**

```
    @using AppEcp.Models       
    <div class="dx-fieldset-header">@ViewData["2ndSubTitle"]</div>
                <div class="dx-field">
                    <div class="dx-field-label">Members</div>
                    <div class="dx-field-value">
                        @(Html
                            .DevExtreme()
                            .SelectBox()
                            .DataSource(d => d
                                .Mvc()
                                .Controller("Members")
                                .LoadAction("Get")
                                .Key("Warriars")
                            )
                            .DisplayExpr("Warriars")
                            .ValueExpr("Warriars")
                            .SearchEnabled(true)
                        )
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvHZA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your popup window is extended. It looks like you have items in SelectBox. Check out that DisplayExpr, ValueExpr has the correct values.